Disconnecting I2C from powered battery gauge IC to rest of the unpowered circuit
The LTC2944 is leaking current into my unpowered side of the circuit, cutting the traces between this IC and the rest of the circuit fixed it.
Can I do the following to prevent this leakage? When the device is unpowered 3V3 volts should go to 0 V, charge fluctuates from 12V to 14V since it is connected to a lead acid battery:


What is "the following"? What was the circuit before you did "that" to it?

The mosfets on SDA and SCL. Before I added the mosfets, SDA and SCL where directly connected to the rest of the circuit
